# MVC model not binding to dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using ASP.Net MVC4 (Razor). I have the following code:

`Dictionary<string, OccasionObject> occasionList = new Dictionary<string, OccasionObject>()`

The key is a string of the category of the occasion. The occassion object has 3 properties: `isAttending(bool)`, `ID(int)`, and `Name(string)`

In my cshtml file, I do the following:

```
@foreach(string s in model.occasionList .Keys)
{
   foreach(var o in model.occasionList .Keys[s])
   {
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.occasionList[s].FirstOrDefault(ev=>ev.ID == o.ID).isAttending);
   }
}
```

This binds perfectly on the load, checking boxes that I have manually checked in SQL. However, when I POST this model back to the server, the occasionList dictionary is null. The model is binding fine because other properties I have in the model are still returned.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Dom

Comment: It seems you are using FirstOrDefault on OccasionObject, isn't the dictionary `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<OccasionObject>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, OccasionObject>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model binder treats the dictionary as a collection, if you imagine the dictionary as an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<OccasionObject>>>` it is easy to understand why it isn't bound.

What `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.occasionList[s].FirstOrDefault(ev=>ev.ID == o.ID).isAttending);` is generating is:

`<input type="checkbox" name="occasionList[0].Value.isAttending" ../>`

so the Key is missing.

Try this:

```
@Html.Hidden("occasionList.Index", s)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=>m.occasionList[s].FirstOrDefault(ev=>ev.ID == o.ID).isAttending);
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.occasionList[s].Key)
```

The first hidden is because you potentially will have your indexes out of order, [**and explicitly providing an ".Index"**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) is the only way to have the model binder work under those circumstances.

[**Here's**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) another resource that describes model binding to collections.

Comment: Awesome article. Makes sense. Ill let you know if this works once Ive tried it.